# users, users_role and user_permissions database design best practice?

Tags: database-design

There are different user types, e.g. owner, staff and website_user, who have different roles, e.g. accountant, data entry operator, manager and help desk. The application will have resources and a role has specific permissions.

[image]

Each role has specific permissions on website resources. Should the user_type table be connected with two tables i.e. role and users or should it be connected with one table?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL. PS Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PS [Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/266284) PS You give no specification, how could others "refine" a design? (Rhetorical.)

Comment: What is your 1 specific question? What published DB design textbook/reference are you following? What method? What are its steps? Where is the 1st place you are stuck? Why/how are you stuck? You essentially ask us to (re)write a textbook for an unidentified method & bespoke tutorial with no details on what you misunderstand or do or don't understand. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs. [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [“help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097)

Comment: Reviewing ERDs requires knowledge of your business case and data relationships. We can't infer them from the names of tables and columns. However, I would point out that there is an ambiguity around how to relate users to permissions... through roles (and a user can only have one role in this design)? Or through the user_control bridge table? If you gave permissions via the bridge table and the role_id for the permission isn't the role the user is assigned to, that's a problem.

Comment: I don't think this site is intended for ongoing coaching like this. Instead, I recommend getting this book and reading through it. It will give you a thorough understanding of normalization and data modeling practices.  https://www.amazon.com/Modeling-Essentials-Third-Graeme-Simsion/dp/0126445516/ref=sr_1_1?crid=3OXS9J5HAZ6R4&keywords=data+modeling+simsion&qid=1679444693&sprefix=data+modeling+simsion%2Caps%2C155&sr=8-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the diagram, the user_type table seems redundant *for permissions*. Assume you have an 'owners' type. All owners have a set of permissions. So, create a role called owners and add the users that are owners to it. Done.

If you want a type attribute (for other reasons) on the user entity then it should only be "connected" to the user table.

Answer (score 0):

This type of design will depend upon your use case, but for a good reference, maybe take a look at the [SCIM Schema](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/inline-errata/rfc7643.html) used in OAuth 2.0 architectures.

A key point to understand is that there are bounded contexts here, and not a one size fits all solution. In OAuth 2.0, the following type of information is stored in the authorization server, where personally identifiable information needs to be managed carefully due to regulations like GDPR.

- Subject (generated value)
- Name (PII)
- Email (PII)
- Country code
- Tenant ID

Meanwhile these fields might vary across business solutions and be stored in business data, possibly differently for different products. Roles are not always a good fit for all scenarios, eg if there is no-one to administer them. Therefore OAuth 2.0 has a claims concept that can vary depending on the use case, and include roles when needed.

- Role
- Roles (array)
- Permissions for a role
- Subscription level
- Branches (areay)

User info can be a complicated topic, so I would model things only in terms of your own bounded context, and any systems you might need to integrate with. Aim to avoid too grand a solution.